# What is the correct syntax for the code

Tags: php

```
<input type="radio" name="rdbtnques1">

<input type="radio" name="rdbtnques2">
```

//php code

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['txt']);$i++)
{
echo $chk =  $_POST['rdbtnques.$i'];
}
```

I want to know the correct syntax for the above code

Comment: That depends on what you want to do

Comment: isn't this a correct syntax already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this

```
echo $chk =  $_POST['chkques.$i'];
```

to

```
echo $chk =  $_POST['chkques'.$i];
```

Answer (score 0):

just put the $_POST['txt'] in a variable

Like: $text = $_POST['txt'];

in that way it is much more easier and readable.

Answer (score 0):

Your question could do with being made a bit clearer, but I think this is what you want:

```
for( $i=0 ; $i<count( $_POST['txt'] ) ; $i++ )
{
    echo $chk = $_POST['rdbtnques'.$i];
}
```